# Django view bypass render request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have a table with data and a button in which the user can delete the whole object, I implemented a template where the user is supposed to be redirected so he can choose between confirm the delete or cancel it.

But when I click the delete button it instantly delete the object, any idea on how to tell the view to first go to that template and then, if it's the case, delete the object?

Here is the **template**: `borrar_oficio.html` I want to be redirected after clicking the delete button:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<p>Are you sure you want to delete {{ item }}?</p>

<form action="{% url 'oficios:borrar' item.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <a href="{% url 'oficios:list' %}">Cancelar</a>

    <input type="submit" name="Confirmar">
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Here is the piece of the **template** where the button is:

```
 <form action="{% url 'oficios:borrar' oficio.folio  %}" method='POST'>
 {% csrf_token %}
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
 </form>
```

Here is the method that deletes the object in `views.py`

```
@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def borrar_oficio(request, pk):
    oficio = Oficio.objects.get(folio=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        oficio.delete()
        return redirect('oficios:list')
    context = {'item': oficio}
    return render(request, "borrar_oficio.html", context)
```

And my `urls.py` of that app:

```
app_name = 'oficios'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.lista_oficios, name="list"),
    path('crear/', views.crear_oficio, name="crear"),
    path('editar_oficio/<str:pk>', views.editar_oficio, name="editar"),
    path('borrar_oficio/<str:pk>', views.borrar_oficio, name="borrar"),
    path('dependencia/', views.agregar_dependencia, name="dependencia"),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button on the form sends a `POST` request to the view, which is valid and therefore it does the delete and then redirects the user. You render the `borrar_oficio.html` template if that same view is hit with a `GET` request, but that's not happening from the trash button.

If you want to get confirmation from the user that they want to submit the deletion request, then you can do this with javascript on the form. Something like this would present a confirm dialog;

```
<form action="{% url 'oficios:borrar' oficio.folio  %}" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to delete the object?');">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar">
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>.
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah I thought that solution too, but with `onclick="return confirm('¿Are you sure you want to delete it?')"` on the `button`, do you recommend me to use JS instead? Like in your answer. Thanks

Comment: Using `onsubmit` should work better for this